# Django S3: The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I'm following a course and I believe I'm doing everything the guy says step by step,
however, I'm running into a problem where I cant output images to my django website from Amazon buckets.

i get

`<Error> <Code>InvalidRequest</Code> <Message>The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.</Message> <RequestId>FBT5M3QQ69AF3QNB</RequestId> <HostId>L8MYNGNFtHoMzCIn8zQZLaIIzrtWpSE31tG4zeIr1o/XqdudSvvPhV9fUEBB5EiNvuWHtM+WqQc=</HostId> </Error>`

These are my

*setting.py*

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), ]
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')  # user uplaoded content
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'


AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '**********'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '********'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucket-name'
```

The files are getting uploaded to the bucket successfully, but they won't show on the web page...

Comment: Any fix yet? Im also stuck on this.

Comment: @DenzelHooke hey, it's been a while but from what I remember I added these lines to setting.py   
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'eu-west-2'
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = 's3v4'
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
...... This One
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'eu-west-2' will depend on what region you're in.
Hope that helps.